# Search for unknown special character in CSV files in unix

Tags: csv, unix, special-characters

I have huge csv files in unix . I am trying to read the unknown special characters and fix the same. But due to the sizes of the csv files (Min file size is 5 GB). i am not able to spot any special characters. Kindly help.

Sample files:

```
"ABC","DEF","123","2022-02-28 09:00:00.046283","ABCDEF"
```

Tried regex and SED but did not work. I am looking to replace the special char with SPL

Comment: Please, post a proper testable sample data with the related expected output.
Also, as this is not a free coding service, we'd appreciate seeing some
attempt first. Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way of hunting for unwanted junk is to progressively delete all characters you are happy with.

So, if you are expecting and happy with letters and digits, blank spaces and tabs, punctuation and new lines, use `tr` to suppress them and see what's left:

```
tr -d '[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]\n' < YOURFILE.CSV
```

These are called *"POSIX character classes"* if you want to look them up. You can do them explicitly too, e.g.:

```
tr -d '[A-Z][a-z][0-9]&:;,.'
```

If the unwanted characters are especially weird, pipe the output through `xxd` to see it in hex:

```
tr - d '...' < YOURFILE.CSV | xxd
```